# What are the applications of quantum shuffle multiplication?

Tags: number-theory, probability-theory, harmonic-analysis, quantum-groups, statistical-mechanics

I am writing a research paper on quantum shuffle multiplication, and there is just one piece that I'm missing: I want to give one or several examples of its applications, and so far I have not been able to find any by searching online.